# Keith Wood Datepick : Display alert when selected date is today

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using Keith Wood jQuery Datepick: http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html and have been trying to get an alert to work when the selected date is today. The ID of my calendar input is 'appdate'.  The best I've managed is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#appdate').datepick({
closeAtTop: false,
alignment: 'bottomLeft',
firstDay: 1,
dateFormat: 'DD d M yyyy',
showOnFocus: true,
showTrigger: '#calPic',
defaultDate: +1,
minDate: 0,
yearRange: 'c-1:c+1',
onDate: function(date) {return {selectable: date.getDay() > 0};},
onSelect: function(date) {
var istoday = $.datepick.today();
var picked = $('#appdate').datepick('getDate');
if (picked == istoday) {
alert('You selected today.'+ istoday + picked);
$('#appdate').datepick('clear');
$('#appdate').datepick('option', {minDate: +1});
$('#appdate').datepick('show');
}}
});
});
</script>
```

...but it doesn't work.  If I change the line: if (picked == istoday) to: if (picked != istoday) and select todays date from the calendar then I'll get the alert and it shows that both variables seem to be the same.

I don't understand why my original code doesn't work.  I must be missing something obvious.

Also, the final line of code should make the calendar pop up again once the date field has been cleared but it doesn't.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a date comparison issue, you are using object comparison so since both the date variables refers to different object it returns false.. so try

```
if (picked.getTime() == istoday.getTime()) {
}
```

Comment: Hi - Thanks but I can't get that to work. I just get 'picked.getTime is not a function'.